# Express app deployed successfully on Azure but still nothing work

Tags: node.js, azure, express

Azure deployed this app with successfully flag, but homepage response with 500 status

index.js:

```
const express = require("express");

const app = express();

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Hello!");
});

app.listen(3000, () => console.log("Hwllo!"));
```

package.json:

```
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: How are you configuring your Azure server?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the variable **`process.env.PORT`** for handling the named pipe port in Azure App Service. See Listen additional port Microsoft Azure Nodejs.

If it does not solve your issue, try to go through KUDU console and look for the particular erros.